# Preview app on macOS High Sierra broken

Tags: macos, high-sierra, pdf, preview

I'm using Preview 10.0 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.

When I select "highlight" to highlight text in a PDF, preview will not highlight the text but "underlines" it instead and then also grays out "highlight" function so it cannot be chosen. This also happens with "Text selection" selected within the Tools menu.

This has always worked in past versions of Preview.

How can I get highlighting to work as it should?